# php create response json array

Tags: php, json

I am having some trouble creating a JSON array. It should look like the following:

```
error : false
   duellid : 1
    questions : [
    {   questionid : xx
       question : lala
       answer : blabla },
    {   questionid : xx
       question : lala
       answer : blabla },
    {   questionid : xx
       question : lala
       answer : blabla }
]
```

Currently the problem is to create the top array questions within the json response :

```
$response["error"] = FALSE;
        $duellid = $duell["id"];

        $response["duell"] = $duellid;
        array_push($return_arr,$response);
        $response = array();
        $resultquestion = $db->getquestions($rows);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultquestion)) {


            $response["question"]["id"] = $row["id"];
            $response["question"]["question"] = $row["question"];
            $response["question"]["answer"] = $row["answer"];
            $response["question"]["active"] = $row["active"];
            $response["question"]["minval"] = $row["minval"];
            $response["question"]["maxval"] = $row["maxval"];

            array_push($return_arr,$response);

        }


        echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

I think it's easy but I can't find the correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$response = array();
$response["error"] = FALSE;
$duellid = $duell["id"];
$response["duell"] = $duellid;
$resultquestion = $db->getquestions($rows);      
$response['questions'] = array();  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultquestion)) { 

    $result = array(
        'questionid' =>   $row["id"],
        'question' => $row["question"],
        'answer' =>  $row["answer"],
        'active' =>  $row["active"],
        'minval' =>  $row["minval"],
        'maxval' =>  $row["maxval"]

    );
    $response['questions'][]  = $result;             

}         
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Damn you were faster, you could describe what you did and why, this would improve this answer.

Comment: @Rocky sorry.i will care from next

Comment: works perfect! thx! hopefully i'm able to add a new array within the questions array by myself ;)

Comment: @MineshPatel you still can edit it (: it may help other to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Array push, push it on end of array. So result is without key questions. instead of:

```
array_push($return_arr,$response);
```

simply put it like that:

```
$response = array('questions'=>array());
$response["error"] = FALSE;
$response["duell"] = $duell["id"];
$resultquestion = $db->getquestions($rows);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultquestion)) {
    $r = array();
    $r["id"] = $row["id"];
    $r["question"] = $row["question"];
    $r["answer"] = $row["answer"];
    $r["active"] = $row["active"];
    $r["minval"] = $row["minval"];
    $r["maxval"] = $row["maxval"];
    $response["questions"][] = $r;

    // or nicer:
    $response["questions"][] = array(
        'question' => 'Your question',
        'answer' => 'any answer'
    );
}
echo json_encode($response);
```